# how to filter in django admin inlines

Tags: django, filter, inlines

```
class StudentsTeacher(admin.TabularInline):
    form = StudentsTeacher
    model = StudentsTeacher

class Teacher_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (StudentsTeacher,)
```

I want add a queryset in StudentsTeacher select with a filter, but it doesn't work, inlines always dispay all.

Answer (score 2):

With the `get_queryset()` method you can override the queryset

```
class Teacher_Admin(admin.TabularInline):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(Teacher_Admin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(<filtering>)
```

You can read more about it in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

Comment: sorry   i means  filter inlines display

Comment: This does NOT work. get_queryset() has no effect on the number of records available in the inlined view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your custom queryset in the formset for inlines

```
    class StudentTeacherFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
        self.queryset = StudentsTeacher.objects.filter(<your custom filter>)

    class StudentsTeacher(admin.TabularInline):
        form = StudentsTeacher
        model = StudentsTeacher
        formset = StudentTeacherFormset

    class Teacher_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = (StudentsTeacher,)
```

Formset can be used to generate a custom queryset for django inlines instead of rendering all the objects of child table in parents admin.

However if anyone finds a solution for providing a filter in django inlines similar to list filter, please let me know.

Comment: This is invalid code. "form = StudentsTeacher" raises: "name  'StudentsTeacher' is not defined"